# Jquery uniform wont design input type=text elements

Tags: jquery, uniform

This picture shows that the input type=text wont be designed by the uniform lib.
[image]

here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Log On</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/Content/JqueryUniform/Aristo/css/uniform.aristo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

         $(document).ready(function () {

             $("input, textarea, select, button").uniform();

         });

    </script>
   </head>
<body>
<form action="/Affiliates/LogOn" method="post">    <div id="login">
            <div class="editor-label">
                <label>User Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input  style="width:90%" type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" />
                <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input style="width:90%" type="password" name="Password" id="Password" />
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                <label style="padding-top:3px;" >Remember Me</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" id="RememberMe" />
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uniform doesn't do text inputs, or text areas at version 1.5. Time of writing this. Uniform styles: Selects (Drop downs), Checkboxes, Radio buttons, File Upload inputs.

Comment: Looks like Uniform does now as of Version 2.1.1. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it might work:

```
input[type=password]
$("input, input[type=password], textarea, select, button").uniform();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the script is not loaded, try to rewrite the path to the library:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.uniform.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```